# WebSockets com ratChet php não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Pessoal estou estudando websockets, e ao tentar seguir vários exemplos encontrados na internet e no próprio site da ratChet eu simplesmente não consigo rodar o servidor, no terminal fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código do exemplo que usei:

**Chat.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

**chat-server.php**

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/src/Chat.php';
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

Cheguei a pensar que seria por causa da porta 8080, mas estou fazendo o testes no meu computador localmente. O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Está rodando. Quando você roda o comando `php arquivo.php` o terminal ficará "pausado" até finalizar essa tarefa. Rode o comando novamente e faça uma conexão via cliente. Caso queira liberar o terminal para outras tarefas, basta rodar o comando `php -f nome-do-arquivo.php &`

Comment: Entendi, mas então no caso de eu implementar uma aplicação baseada em um servidor websocket usando ratChet eu preciso deixar o terminal aberto? ou tem alguma maneira de deixar rodando em segundo plano constantemente? @ValdeirPsr

Comment: Para deixar um processo em `background`, basta rodar `nohup php -f nome-do-arquivo.php &` e para o código sempre rodar quando iniciar/reiniciar o servidor, basta criar um shell script em `/etc/init.d`